# Having problems with creating a DocuSign Connect Listener

Tags: docusignapi

I'm fairly new to DocuSign Connect and I'm trying to code a listener for data updates coming from the service using CodeIgniter. Currently, I'm trying to insert any post variables sent to CodeIgniter in the hopes of studying the data that's actually being passed, but I've been unsuccessful. Here's the part of the code that I have:

```
public function receive()
{
    $post = $_POST;

    $post = serialize($post);

    $results = $this->db->query("insert into capture (`key`,`capturedXML`) values ('temp','".$post."')");
}
```

The problem is that nothing comes out of it, or is empty. I know that information is passed via POST, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Instead of coding a listener application from scratch, consider
   leveraging one of the listener applications that DocuSign has published to GitHub: 
   https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK.  Each
   language-specific folder (Java, .NET, PHP, etc.) contains a
   **Connect** folder that you should be able to utilize as a basis for building your listener.
2. Be sure to ensure that DocuSign Connect is successfully delivering messages to
   the endpoint that you've specified for your listener.  You can do
   this by enabling the **Log** in your Connect configuration settings
   (via the DocuSign UI, select "Enable Log" checkbox for the Connect
   Configuration) -- then triggering an envelope event for which your
   Connect configuration is set to send a notification (example: Send
   an Envelope) -- then checking the log message in DocuSign
   (**Preferences >> Connect >> Logs**).  The log entry that's
   generated when the envelope event occurs should indicate success, if
   the message reached the endpoint.

Finally, if you haven't already, check out the **DocuSign Connect Service Guide** for info about how Connect works, etc.:  http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_Connect_Service_Guide.pdf.